# How do i properly create a new model, fill the fillable fields and then save the relationship?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I think i didn't get the right method to create and save a new model:

```
$newSelling = Selling::create([
    'code'  => $this->code,
    'date'  => $this->date,
]);

$newSelling->customer()->save(Customer::find($this->customer_id));
```

And i get this error:

```
General error: 1364 Field 'customer_id' doesn't have a default value
```

The field **customer_id** is the **belongsTo** key to **Customer::class**

Comment: show me your Sellings migration

Comment: I solved just doing "'customer_id'  => $this->customer_id", thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

**There is a tip: The most internal function is execute**

So first, `find` function of `Customer` model, will be execute. in this function there is a parameter that refer to `customer_id` of this object of class

`Customer::find($this->customer_id)` return null. because there isn't exist the customer with this id or `$this->customer_id` might been empty

So in `save` method parameter there is a null parameter. thus this error occured. because there isn't exist any customer with `$this->customer_id` id.

If you want to see, write `dd(Customer::find($this->customer_id))` in your code.

Comment: The Customer exists because the id is selected from a select